# How do I activate the flashlight during a front-facing camera recording?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

How do I activate the rear-facing flashlight during a front-facing camera recording on the iPhone?

Comment: are you referring to an iPad?  Which one and what system are you running.

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to activate the rear-facing flashlight while the front-facing camera is recording, correct?

Comment: @nohillside Yes

Comment: For me when I open the camera app the flashlight turns off and the button is deactivated in control center. I'm going to guess you will need an app that enables this.

Answer (score 1):

### It seems you can't.

As soon as you press the record button, the option to enable the torch or flash is disabled everywhere. You must decide whether you need any extra brightness beforehand.

[Check this link](https://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/972553) for more info. Note that what @dwightk said in the comments was spot-on, except that instead of apps there are jailbreaks available if you really need this control...